# Change of user identity

Tags: discussion

I have noticed once or twice that a question that I have read in the morning, during the progress of the day appears with a different questioner. Example this [recent one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/what-is-the-weight-equation-through-general-relativity).
It started with a newbie user  Neo ( there have been several starters with this handle) and now it is Dirac. I do not know whether it will still be that by the time your read this.

How can this be done, i.e. change the identity of the questioner?

Answer (score 4):

This is likely due to the fact that OP changed his profile info (username and email which determines the avatar).